# Upcoming football matches feed

Tags: rss, feed, rss-reader, rss2

Is there a way to add a feed or something to a website to show the upcoming football games (who's playing and at what time)?

I was thinking something like this: http://www.bbc.com/sport/football/fixtures

I think they have an RSS feed but I can't find how to utilise it. Is this even the right thing? I've never used any sort of feeds before.

I have found this: market.mashape.com/heisenbug/champions-league-live-scores I'm not sure if it displays the upcoming matches or not, but it's the closest thing I've found. Most of the sports APIs I've found seem to charge quite a lot per month to use. This one has a free version, but I don't fully understand it. It says 50 free per month, but 50 free what? Requests? If so, is it one 'request' per update (which is every 10mins with this plan)? Then it would only last just over 8hrs??? market.mashape.com/heisenbug/champions-league-live-scores/

Thanks

Comment: @Mauricio

I have found this:

https://market.mashape.com/heisenbug/champions-league-live-scores

I'm not sure if it displays the upcoming matches or not, but it's the closest thing I've found. Most of the sports APIs I've found seem to charge quite a lot per month to use. This one has a free version, but I don't fully understand it. It says 50 free per month, but 50 free what? Requests? If so, is it one 'request' per update (which is every 10mins with this plan)? Then it would only last just over 8hrs???

https://market.mashape.com/heisenbug/champions-league-live-scores/pricing

Answer (score 1):

I did found two webpages which supplies the information you need. Since you didn't add source code, I think this answer will suit better for you.

---

First, enter to [ScoresPro](http://www.scorespro.com/free-livescore/) and pick any of the available sports rss feeds.
For this example I select *Soccer.*

Later, enter to [Feedwind](https://feed.mikle.com/), paste the feed URL and press ENTER.

This is the [result](https://feed.mikle.com/widget/v2/?widget_parameter=%7B%22type%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sources%22%3A%5B%7B%22source%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.scorespro.com%2Frss2%2Flive-soccer.xml%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22RSS%22%7D%5D%2C%22name%22%3A%22%22%2C%22width%22%3A0%2C%22height%22%3A%22400%22%2C%22height_by_article%22%3A0%2C%22target%22%3A%22_blank%22%2C%22font%22%3A%22Arial%2C%20Helvetica%2C%20sans-serif%22%2C%22title_font_size%22%3A%2216%22%2C%22item_title_font_size%22%3A%2216%22%2C%22item_description_font_size%22%3A%2212%22%2C%22border%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22css_url%22%3A%22%22%2C%22responsive%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22text_direction%22%3A%22left%22%2C%22text_alignment%22%3A%22left%22%2C%22corner%22%3A%22rounded%22%2C%22scroll%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22auto_scroll%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22auto_scroll_direction%22%3A%22up%22%2C%22auto_scroll_step_speed%22%3A%224%22%2C%22auto_scroll_mc_speed%22%3A%2220%22%2C%22sort%22%3A%22new%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22title_sentence%22%3A%22%22%2C%22title_link%22%3A%22%22%2C%22title_bgcolor%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22title_color%22%3A%22%23505659%22%2C%22title_bgimage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22item_bgcolor%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22item_bgimage%22%3A%22%22%2C%22item_title_length%22%3A%2255%22%2C%22item_title_color%22%3A%22%232e7ec8%22%2C%22item_border_bottom%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22item_description%22%3A%22both%22%2C%22item_link%22%3A%22off%22%2C%22item_description_length%22%3A%22100%22%2C%22item_description_color%22%3A%22%23505659%22%2C%22item_date%22%3A%22on%22%2C%22item_date_format%22%3A%22%25b%20%25e%2C%20%25Y%20%25k%3A%25M%22%2C%22item_date_timezone%22%3A%22%22%2C%22item_description_style%22%3A%22thumbnail%22%2C%22item_thumbnail%22%3A%22crop%22%2C%22item_thumbnail_selection%22%3A%22auto%22%2C%22item_thumbnail_force_https%22%3A%22off%22%2C%22article_num%22%3A%2215%22%2C%22item_player%22%3A%22youtube%22%2C%22keyword_inc%22%3A%22%22%2C%22keyword_exc%22%3A%22%22%7D).

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the sort of things I'm looking for. I'll look more into it and let you know how it goes.